# onEndReached doesn't work as expected using ListView on Android with ReactNative

Tags: android, listview, react-native

I am trying to list hundreds of items in a `ListView` using React-Native on `Android` platform. Version of `react-native` is `0.22`. Here is my `ListView` component:

```
<ListView dataSource={dataSource}
                      onEndReached={onEndReached}
                      renderRow={this.renderRow.bind(this)}/>
```

When the page loads I retrieve batch of data and fullfill datasource as follows:

```
onEndReached(page) {
    let {dataSource = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2})} = this.state;

    return myService.search({page})
        .then(newRows => {
            this.setState({
                dataSource: dataSource.cloneWithRows(newRows),
                page: page
            });
        });
}

renderRow(row){console.log(row.id); // This is printed for all rows regardless of whether it is displayed on the screen or not}
```

Basically what happens is, `onEndReached` function is triggered with a slight slide or sometimes even without any gestures. I thought this function will only be called when all the rows given to dataSource is rendered. Strangely I see that my `renderRow` function is called for all my rows, not just for the row displayed on the screen. I tried using `scrollRenderAheadDistance` but to no avail.

May anyone point me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: The problem was I had my ListView under a ScrollView it was breaking its behaviour. After removing the ListView outside ScrollView it started to work as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was I had my `ListView` under a `ScrollView` it was breaking its behaviour. After removing the `ListView` outside `ScrollView` it started to work as expected.